# expressjs - serving vendors folder on localhost but not on heroku/otherhost

Tags: node.js, express

I'm using expressjs and handlebars to serve webpages. All my javascripts are inside the public/javascripts folder and my stylesheets are inside public/stylesheets.

Loading .css or .js files from inside there works. But now I have a folder public/vendors/bower_components/ with subfolders inside.

On localhost it loads items from inside the vendor folder but not when I serve pages to the public or when I commit it to Heroku.

This is my static folder:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

This is how I include the JS/css:

```
<script src="vendors/bower_components/jquery-toast-plugin/dist/jquery.toast.min.js"></script>
<link href="vendors/bower_components/jquery-toast-plugin/dist/jquery.toast.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

I already tried adding a forward slash to vendors but it still doesn't get served. Folder structure:

```
05/09/2018  13:22                   .
05/09/2018  13:22                   ..
03/09/2018  08:27                   fonts
03/09/2018  08:27                   img
05/09/2018  13:22                   javascripts
03/09/2018  16:40                   lib
05/09/2018  09:49                   stylesheets
05/09/2018  09:45                   vendors
    05/09/2018  09:46                   bower_components
        05/09/2018  09:46                   jquery-toast-plugin
            05/09/2018  09:46                   dist
                06/09/2016  14:49                   jquery.toast.min.css
                06/09/2016  14:49                   jquery.toast.min.js
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is vendors or bower_components directory tracked by git?
If not is any build scripts run by heroku during the deployment? This scripts containes the bower install command?

Comment: I am ashamed to say that was the issue. I was using a Node.js gitignore from gitignore.io and it didn't come to my mind to check that first. Thanks!